# Исчезли все папки в /home/user кроме двух: Загрузки и Рабочий стол

Tags: ubuntu

Обнаружил, что исчезли все папки в /home/user кроме двух: Загрузки и Рабочий стол.

Система ubuntu 11.10 с unity 2d. Кто виноват понятно (наверно я, т.к больше никто не работает за компьютером), а вот что делать непонятно.Никто не сталкивался с таким?

Answer (score 1):

Если проверка не произошла, стоит загрузиться с live-носителя и уже с него проверить файловую систему на ошибки при помощи fsck. На смонтированной ФС лучше такое не делать - можно совсем потерять данные.

Comment: по прошествии двух недель смысла проверять файловую систему по моему нет, или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Не обратил внимание на дату поста.

Answer (score 0):

Иногда такое происходит в случае сбоев файловой системы. Можно выполнить ее проверку командой

```
sudo shutdown -rF now
```

это перегрузит системы и выполнит fsck (довольно долго) после старта. Если есть ошибки, fsck попробует исправить их, и папки, возможно, вернуться.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но не помогло - перезагрузиться система перезагрузилась, но проверять ничего не стала и тем более исправлять